# Cannot retrieve certain public tracks via SoundCloud API calls (403)

Tags: api, soundcloud

Some tracks in my playlist are not being returned when accessed via the SoundCloud API.

For example, here are two tracks in my playlist:

1. http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/169170570?client_id=CLIENT_ID
2. http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/251027701?client_id=CLIENT_ID

The URL for track 1 returns a JSON object and also appears properly in my /playlists request. However, track 2 gives me a 403 in the URL above and is not present in my /playlists request.

Why is this happening? As far as I can tell, track 2 is a public track and should be accessible. The interesting thing is I can still stream track 2 by adding /stream to the end of the URL:

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/251027701/stream?client_id=CLIENT_ID

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely that the artist has blocked API access to this track.

> SoundCloud has introduced an option for right holders to disable all API access to tracks by default, returning this 403 error when requested

From: 
[SoundCloud API URLs timing out and then returning error 403 on about 50% of tracks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360202/soundcloud-api-urls-timing-out-and-then-returning-error-403-on-about-50-of-trac/36529330#36529330)

Comment: This is not the case. It's a bug with SoundCloud's API on the server side, unfortunately.

Comment: And how can we see the difference between a bug and intentional behaviour?

Comment: The post you cited is mine, and I have continued to email with SoundCloud and they can't provide a single link, screenshot, or source where artists are allows to block API requests. Whenever I ask them, they stop replying. So far it appears that it's just a statement they made because they don't have a dedicated API team to fix this.

Comment: Dean: seeing this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477095/soundcloud-api-returns-0-tracks-for-user I'm afraid you are right. Perhaps @nickf can comment on this...