# Soundcloud API returns 0 tracks for user

Tags: api, soundcloud

For a client of mine I used the Soundcloud API to show tracks on his website.
now it had stopped working, the API returns 0 tracks.

https://api.soundcloud.com/users/1525250/tracks?client_id=dec73200bd1c369969eb9df50f4a190b

I checked his account and all tracks have the right permissions.

[image: screenshot permissions],

What am I doing wrong?

(website of client) [eelkekleijn.nl](http://eelkekleijn.nl)

Comment: Hi Preetam, welcome to SO. Your question doesn't sound directly programming oriented. Have you read the license terms of SounCloud? Maybe end of trial period?

Comment: Hi J. Chomel, I know its not realy code related but api related. but this is the only place you can contact soundcloud with questions :( 
https://developers.soundcloud.com/support

I know my api is working because I can get trakcs of other users. Only not from my client. (it was working before). It seems like a bug in the soundcloud api.

Comment: Unfortunately more people are running into this issue and soundcloud does not seem to provide information about how to fix this. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360202/soundcloud-api-urls-timing-out-and-then-returning-error-403-on-about-50-of-trac/36529330#36529330 and @Dean 's comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231488/cannot-retrieve-certain-public-tracks-via-soundcloud-api-calls-403/36569727?noredirect=1#comment62470171_36569727

Comment: thanks for the reply. I saw those posts. Only the tracks i'm calling have api permissions (I have access to the account and settings). So it's not about the new permission settings. maybe there is a setting hidden somewhere. Lets hope they can fix this asap.

Answer (score 0):

All rate limits on the SoundCloud API are currently calculated against a client application's client id so you need to change your application client id

[Read More](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits)

Eg.

https://api.soundcloud.com/users/1525250/tracks?client_id=02gUJC0hH2ct1EGOcYXQIzRFU91c72Ea

Comment: If I register a new app (first thing I tried) with a new id it also returns empty. I see your id does work.
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/1525250/tracks?client_id=212f01d8f5d9544944ecd329d7b02dce.

I got a reaction from soundcloud, but that does not explain why your id is working:  _
So the reason for this is that your account has actually had API access restricted. This is because one of the listed rightsholders on your account is Universal. Universal have requested that accounts they are affiliated with in this way - have their API access restricted. _

Answer (score 0):

SoundCloud allows certain users to block API requests.  In this case, this user has blocked the ability to view their information via the SoundCloud API.

The only way around this is to use an API Key internal to SoundCloud, such as the one [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/soundcloud.py) uses to download tracks.